# Get array of keys based on values from another array

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of objects that looks like this

```
let myArray = [
  {item1: true},
  {item2: false},
  {item3: true},
  {item4: false}
]
```

How would I iterate though this to return a new array of `true` values that looks like this:

```
let newArray = ['item1', 'item3']
```

I found this function but it only returns single items:

```
function findKey(map, term) {
  var found = [];
  for(var property in map) {
    if(map.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      for(var key in map[property]) {
        if(map[property].hasOwnProperty(key) && key === term) {
          found.push(property);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the first key of each array item via `Object.keys()`, and use this to filter items with a true value for that first key, and then complete the process with a call to `map()` to transform the item to a value based on the same "first key" technique:

```js
let myArray = [
  {item1: true},
  {item2: false},
  {item3: true},
  {item4: false}
]

let result = myArray
.filter(item => item[ Object.keys(item)[0] ] === true)
.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: wait, is this only going to work id the keys are in the format item + i? those are just placeholder keys

Comment: @cup_of you're welcome! Please consider accepting this answer if it has been helpful :-)

Comment: @cup_of this will work by selecting the first key of each item - does that suit your requirements?

Comment: yup this will work. thanks man. ill accept it when it lets me

Comment: @cup_of no problems :-)

Comment: fyi, `Object.values()` exists [1] and can reduce verbosity:

`.filter(item => Object.values(item)[0])`


[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `myArray` always contains objects with only 1 property.

```
let newArray = myArray
    .map(item => Object.entries(item)[0])
    .filter(([key, value]) => value)
    .map(([key, value]) => key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `reduce` to build the desired output.  The handler of the function `reduce` will get the `keys` and check for each `value === true`.

This approach checks for the whole set of keys within an object.  Further, this way you only use one loop.

```js
let myArray = [{item1: true},{item2: false},{item3: true},{item4: false}],
    result = myArray.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(Object.keys(c).filter(k => c[k] === true)), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Shortest

```
let newArray = myArray.map( x=>Object.keys(x)[0] ).filter( (k,i)=>myArray[i][k] );
```

In above solution first we use: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which works as for-loop to get array of keys (using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) `["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]`. Then we [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that array by choose only those keys for which original array object has `true`. e.g `myArray[0]["item1"] -> true` (we use fact that filter funtion takes array element (k) and its index (i) which is the same for elements in `myArray`). In `map` and `filter` we use [arrow functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/).

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @RoyScheffers This is very short code which use standard js functions (ES6) however I can explain it - I update my answer

Comment: Hi Kamil. I know it's a short example and to those who are familiar with `.map()` `.filter()` and arrow functions will be able to read it and understand it, however, not everyone is at that level. By the clarification you provided, you've added value that will help newcomers to the language.

Answer (score 1):

Something much optimized than the accepted answer would look like this:

```
const arr = [
  { item1: true },
  { item2: false },
  { item3: true },
  { item4: false }
]

const result = [];
const len = arr.length;

for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
  const obj = arr[i];
  const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];

  if(obj[key]) {
    result.push(key);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

There is only one loop over the array, instead of `map` and `filter` which ends up looping twice.